# Can someone please explain to me the way to calculate the number of bills and coins of change in python?

Tags: python, module

So I know for calculating the **number** of bills and coins given back from the change (ex: 2 $100 bills), you need to use the `%` module.

But why do you need to `%` module and how come people don't just subtract?

For example, I have $100 change

I know I have to change it to pennies so that makes it 10000cents

`cents = int(change*100) ---->10000cents`

so when I calculate how many $100 bills, $50 bills, and so on of change I have to get back, how come I need to to % and why do I need to divide?

Ex:
`cents = change*100`

`hundered_dollars = int(cents /10000)` If I divide here, `10000/10000` that equals 1, but when I `print(hundered_dollars)` it prints it as 0!

`cents = cents %10000` I suspect it's because of this %

I am super new to programming, and I can't just wrap my head around it!

Comment: Hard to understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: I just do not get why you are supposed to use the % thing and I keep seeing other people that don't subtract at all from the code! like here http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/python-program-designed-calculate-european-change-transaction-works-perfectly-fine-need-ge-q4283254 @Defalt

Comment: how come they don't subract? how do they keep track of how much change is left to calculate?

Comment: `%` is modular division. It returns the remainder.

For example:

`5 % 3 = 2`

Three goes into five once with two remaining. It's also called remainder division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is not a module; it is called the modulus (or "remainder") operator.

It is the counterpart of integer divison:

```
9 == 4 * 2 + 1

9 // 4 == 2    # integer divison
9 % 4 == 1     # remainder
```

so, for example:

```
# paying $63.51
x = 6351 // 1000      # == 6    maximum number of $10.00 bills
y = 6351 % 1000       # == 351  $3.51 not payable in 10s.

# you could instead do
y = 6351 - (6351 // 1000) * 1000

# this would give the same result,
# but you've got to admit it's a lot
# less readable.
```

Comment: ohmygod thank you so much! so the % takes count of how much you have left to pay and you can use that in the next set of bills (such as going down to $5! so now I do z = 351//500 is 0 so you cannot use any $5 bills and it leaves 351%500=702 left?

Comment: You can also do both these steps at once using the divmod function: `x, y = divmod(6531, 1000)`.